# Can not see carousel images

Tags: php

I want to create a carousel. This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="/images/m1.jpg" alt="Poza 1" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/m2.jpg" alt="Poza 2" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/m3.jpg" alt="Poza 3" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/m3.jpg" alt="Poza 3" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have all the pictures in the folder images...but they don't appear. So when I go in the images folder and I want to see the pictures, appear this:

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/files/public_html/6/skins/shinra/google_view.template.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/files/public_html/6/skins/shinra/view1.template.php
>   on line 19

Does anyone have an idea on whats going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: then it is sure that your `google_view.template.php` is in correct path :)

Comment: to clarify, your problem isn't in the HTML you posted above.  It's in `view1.template.php` on line 19.  It's not finding `google_view.template.php`